# How do I select data from previous years in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I tried using `WHERE (YEAR(InceptionDate), -3, GETDATE())`, but

```
SELECT 
    CompanyName, ServiceSubCodeName, subdiagnosisName,
    YEAR(InceptionDate), 
    SUM(AmountCharged) AmountCharged,
    SUM(AmountAllowed) AmountAllowed, 
    SUM(AmountDenied) AmountDenied,  
    SUM(AmountDenied) * 100.0 / SUM(AmountCharged) AS DeniedPart
FROM 
    Fact.ClaimDetailVw
WHERE 
    (YEAR(InceptionDate), -5, GETDATE())
    -- WHERE YEAR(InceptionDate) = 2019 AND   
    AND VetCompanyName <> 'Unknown' 
GROUP BY
    CompanyName, ServiceSubCodeName, subdiagnosisName, 
    YEAR(InceptionDate)
HAVING 
    SUM(AmountCharged) <> 0
ORDER BY 
    CompanyName
```

But I get an error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

This is not a data issue so not providing the dataset. As you can see, it works in the commented code but that is only for 2019. I want last 5 years data

Comment: where `Year(InceptionDate) < year(getdate())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the year you want as the start date

```sql
--get start year
    
declare @StartYear  int = year(getdate()) - 5;
    
select @StartYear
    
SELECT
    CompanyName,
    ServiceSubCodeName,
    subdiagnosisName,
    YEAR(InceptionDate), 
    SUM(AmountCharged) AmountCharged,
    SUM(AmountAllowed) AmountAllowed , 
    SUM(AmountDenied) AmountDenied , 
    SUM(AmountDenied)*100.0/SUM(AmountCharged) ASDeniedPert
FROM Fact.ClaimDetailVw
WHERE YEAR(InceptionDate) > @StartYear  
AND VetCompanyName <> 'Unknown' 
GROUP BY  CompanyName,ServiceSubCodeName,subdiagnosisName, YEAR(InceptionDate)
HAVING SUM(AmountCharged) <> 0
ORDER BY CompanyName
```

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off calculating the 1st of the year 5 years ago, and then querying on that date/time value.

```
SELECT 
    CompanyName, ServiceSubCodeName, subdiagnosisName,
    YEAR(InceptionDate), 
    SUM(AmountCharged) AmountCharged,
    SUM(AmountAllowed) AmountAllowed, 
    SUM(AmountDenied) AmountDenied,  
    SUM(AmountDenied) * 100.0 / SUM(AmountCharged) AS DeniedPart
FROM 
    Fact.ClaimDetailVw
WHERE 
    InceptionDate >= DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    AND VetCompanyName <> 'Unknown' 
GROUP BY
    CompanyName, ServiceSubCodeName, subdiagnosisName, 
    YEAR(InceptionDate)
HAVING 
    SUM(AmountCharged) <> 0
ORDER BY 
    CompanyName
```

If you want to exclude this year - you can add

```
    AND InceptionDate < DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

If the column InceptionDate is defined as a date data type - then you can use DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 4, 1, 1).

Comment: This is the correct answer, it uses a SARGE-able `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

If you want for the last 5 years including this year …

```
WHERE YEAR(InceptionDate) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 4 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
```

… and if you want for the previous 5 years NOT including the current year …

```
WHERE YEAR(InceptionDate) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5 AND YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
```

… this is a safe approach given it allows for the potential for future dated data (i.e. budget/forecast data).

Comment: getting an incorrect syntax error near VetCompanyName